# Extra files in Windows Store app package

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

just wondering if it's possible to include some files (one txt file in this case) in the app package that I need in the application folder. The thing is that I might use a piece of code that requires the license to be included in the app as a text file, and I think this would be one way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, it's really no different than including images for instance. And if you need to process the file within your app you can access it via its local path or explicitly use the `ms-appx:///` protocol.

See [How to reference content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh781215.aspx) and [How to load file resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh965322%28v=win.10%29.aspx) for more details.

Comment: I see, so we need to include it in the solution and mark it as a resource, instead of actually doing something specific when creating the app package?

Comment: correct, just mark it as Content which it may be by default in many cases

Answer (score 1):

Just include the file in your project with `Build Action` set to `Content`. You can put it in any folder you like.

The file can then be accessed from the app either using the `ms-appx:` protocol or using the `StorageFolder` API:

```
var license = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("license.txt");
```